# How to sort and search in a very huge file that can't be loaded into memory?

Tags: c#, .net, string, sorting, search

In my recent interview I was asked about searching a string in a very huge file full of texts, that can't be loaded into main/RAM memory. For example a file of size 1tb when RAM is 1gb.

I found many articles about this, few even on stackoverflow but not much convincing. For SEARCHING, people are suggesting to use chunk of data or read file line by line something like that. Couldn't find answer about, how to read line by line without loading file and what if search string presents in multiple chunks (some part of the string in one chunk, some part is in another chunk and can be many chunks if search string is quite long), on what basis we decide chunk size. I've many such kind of small question because same was asked by interviewer.

I believe this is not hypothetical question anymore, so anyone who has actually implemented this or have fair idea about this please share your 
thoughts. Many thanks in advance.

If possible suggest some algorithm or code in C# .Net.

Comment: Depending on what's in the file, I would tend to look at the example of a database for inspiration.  Databases build indexes to do sorting and searching.  If there is no index, then then need to rely on a *table scan* to do searching. If you can figure out what kind of sorting/searching you need to do, you can read in the file as a stream and build an index ("a record keyed with 'flydog' begins at offset 23456").  This can make sense if the indexed "field" is much smaller than the "record" size. Absent an index, you can search by reading things in as a stream

Comment: I've updated my question specific to search. Now, as we can't load entire file in to memory then how it is possible to search into this. If we load some chunks at a time, first I don't know how to load part of data in C# .Net (easily can be done in db but not sure about file), secondly, what if search string is very large, larger than the chunk size. In this case search string will break into many chunks and if we search in a particular chunk we won't find it.

Comment: Open a stream to read the file.  Do buffered reads (I suggest 4k buffers), Start searching - you'll need to write your own searching algorithms (there's lots of info available for how to search for things).  If you are searching for the string `"Hello"` and you see `"Hel"` as the last three characters in your buffer, you'll need to read in the new buffer (a bit like a page fault).  Most likely, you will work with a pair of buffers (say A and B).  You read into A, start searching, when you get to the end, read in B, and mark A unused.  When you get to the end of B, read in A, lather, rinse...

Comment: @Flydog57, it makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still a bit vague on what you're actually looking for, however hope this helps.

For large files you could use `memorymappedfile` :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netframework-4.8

Sample from msdn:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes
        long length = 0x20000000; // 512 megabytes

        // Create the memory-mapped file.
        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data", FileMode.Open,"ImgA"))
        {
            // Create a random access view, from the 256th megabyte (the offset)
            // to the 768th megabyte (the offset plus length).
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
            {
                int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor));
                MyColor color;

                // Make changes to the view.
                for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
                {
                    accessor.Read(i, out color);
                    color.Brighten(10);
                    accessor.Write(i, ref color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct MyColor
{
    public short Red;
    public short Green;
    public short Blue;
    public short Alpha;

    // Make the view brighter.
    public void Brighten(short value)
    {
        Red = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Red + value);
        Green = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Green + value);
        Blue = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Blue + value);
        Alpha = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Alpha + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replyin @sommmmen even for unclean question. I've updated my question specific to search in large files. Suppose we load one chunks at a time, what if search string is very large, larger than the chunk size. In this case search string will break into many chunks and if we search in a particular chunk we won't find it.

From given msdn link, I understand we can load random data from file, but we need to read whole file to find search string. I believe above code will also work in loop until there is no data to read but still not sure how to match.